# Java regexto match tuples

Tags: java, regex, string, tuples

I need to extract tuples out of string

e.g. `(1,1,A)(2,1,B)(1,1,C)(1,1,D)`

and thought some regex like:

```
String tupleRegex = "(\\(\\d,\\d,\\w\\))*";
```

would work but it just gives me the first tuple. What would be proper regex to match all the tuples in the strings.

Comment: "*it just gives me the first tuple*" Can we see your code? If I am not mistaken your regex should match entire `(1,1,A)(2,1,B)(1,1,C)(1,1,D)` and in group 1 it should contain *last* tuple `(1,1,D)`, not first one.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `*` from the regex and iterate over the matches using a `java.util.regex.Matcher`:

```
String input = "(1,1,A)(2,1,B)(1,1,C)(1,1,D)";
String tupleRegex = "(\\(\\d,\\d,\\w\\))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(tupleRegex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The `*` character is a quantifier that matches zero or more tuples. Hence your original regex would match the entire input string.

Answer (score 2):

One line solution using `String.split()` method and here is the pattern `(?!^\\()(?=\\()`

```
Arrays.toString("(1,1,A)(2,1,B)(1,1,C)(1,1,D)".split("(?!^\\()(?=\\()"))
```

output:

```
[(1,1,A), (2,1,B), (1,1,C), (1,1,D)]
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kX4zX1/1) as well.

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    ^                        the beginning of the string
    \(                       '('
  )                        end of look-ahead
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \(                       '('
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: The pattern in your answer seems complicated , \((\d,\d,\w)\) seems to work as well.

Comment: it look for `(` but not the beginning one and split the string. Is it complicated?